# I need Madwifi drivers for Asus EeePC 701

Tags: drivers, wireless-networking, eee-pc

I've been trying to setup the Asus EeePC for enterprise WLAN as per the guide here: http://wiki.eeeuser.com/wpa_default_xandros however the link to the madwifi drivers appears to be dead. The download site repeatedly reports that the server is down and to try ten minutes later.

I have tried later to no avail. I have also tried looking and the madwifi site itself and most links seem to be broken or dead. Googling has only lead me to links to the madwifi site or the previously mentioned tutorial.

If anyone has a copy of these drivers I'd really appriciate them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the madwifi drivers from their mirror on sourceforge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/madwifi/

Comment: The tutorial above gave me the impression that the drivers had been (necessarily) recompiled for the particular kernel in the default install of the 701.

Comment: It looks like you may be right, although you probably won't find it difficult to compile them yourself.  You can find instructions to download and compile them yourself here http://madwifi.net/HOWTO/ in the downloading and compiling section.  It looks like sourceforge is out of date anyway